# Filter Invoices or Bills by Tracking Option

Tags: xero-api

I'm trying to filter invoices and bills by Tracking Option in the Xero API to show costs to a project where the project is set in a Tracking Category/Option on the Bill or Invoice.

[image]

This value appears in the returned object:

```
["tracking"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(XeroAPI\XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\LineItemTracking)#18755 (1) {
      ["container":protected]=>
      array(4) {
        ["tracking_category_id"]=>
        string(36) "8a29ae32-c0f1-43b4-a4aa-09293ad182be"
        ["tracking_option_id"]=>
        NULL
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Project"
        ["option"]=>
        string(4) "2455"
      }
    }
  }
```

I've tried to use `LineItems` `LineItemTracking` and many other guesses in the Where:

```
$where = "Type=="ACCPAY"&&tracking_category_option=="' . $projectNo . '";
```

But I can't get anything to work.

Does anyone know how to achieve filtering on the tracking categories or options or can think of a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a GET invoices call you will always receive a summary response. You would need to use pagination or a status filter to get a detailed response which includes the tracking option details.

As far as I am aware it is not possible to filter by tracking option in the API as the tracking option is inside a tracking table inside a line item table inside the invoice, but someone else in this forum may have a suggestion. Otherwise you would need to get all the invoices and filter the results outside of the API.

Comment: Thanks - I had an error which was stopping me disabling the summary so I'm now seeing the values, but as you say, I don't think it is possible to filter them which seems really poor.

Comment: Xero have confirmed this isn't possible.